# Query only the required mview from the union

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I have materialized view manually partitioned by month

```
create materialized view MV_MVNAME_201001 as
select MONTH_ID, AMOUNT, NAME
from TABLE_NAME_201001
```

201002, 201003, ..., 201112, 2012, 2009

Now i need query from these views, take only the required views.

Is it possible, without involving the client side?

**example query**

```
select AMOUNT, NAME
from ( 
    --union all mview
)
where month_id >= 201003
  and month_id <  201101
```

should look only to the MV_MVNAME_201003 .. MV_MVNAME_201012

Comment: you can create the MV on prebuilt table, and use a partitioned table. I'm not sure that prebuilt is mandatory. Surely you can have a partitioned Materialized View.

Comment: Now the tables in the large amounts of data, and create a common, even partitioned mview is not possible

Comment: maybe an index can help... it depends on how many months you have.

Answer (score 0):

The materialized view is "*materialized*". It is a phisical table with data within it.

The query that produce the materialized view is used only when you refresh data, not on querys.

Oracle doesn't know where data came from(in your case - a union from several distinct tables), unless you specify it somehow, for example - a column.

**But** in your specific case you have the column month_id, on witch you can partition the table. 
When you specify the month or range of months, it will scan only the correspondent partitions.

**UDPATE**: 
Now I understand better your question, but I cannot give you a better answer. Your question has nothing to do with mviews. Mviews can be tables. Your problem is the same. You want to select only from some tables, dynamic. For this was created partitioning. Probably old dogs know a trick...